# How to use event of control inherited?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, custom-controls, inheritance

I have create a Custom Control `ImageView : Grid`, I need a Load event of Grid, but I don't have XAML, I don't know how to make event without XAML.

How to can I create or inherit a Load event for my Custom Control?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach to the Load event of the base class you can do so using the usual method:

```
public ImageView()
{
    Load += LoadHandler;
}
```

If you want to expose it to use, then Load will still be available from the base class.

Can you please be more specific on what you're looking for?